# Center Bootstrap Menu Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to tackle this for hours, but I can't understand how to get my menu bar to center, I've tried applying different margins and paddings but obviously that won't center on all devices.

Here is the page showing the menu bar: http://newton-poppleford-weather.co.uk/index.htm

I don't want to paste in the scripts as they are huge, but please could someone give me a hint as to where I should be looking and if I should remove any margins I've set?

Thanks,

William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I hope this works for you.

Add this to your custom styles:

```
.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
 }

.navbar-toggle { 
  position: absolute; 
  float: none;
  right: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block; 
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Then amend your HTML by doing the following:

- add `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` to `navbar-header`
- add `<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="index.htm">Newton&nbsp;Poppleford&nbsp;Weather</a></li>` within `navbar-collapse`

so your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle&nbsp;navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.htm">Newton&nbsp;Poppleford&nbsp;Weather</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="index.htm">Newton&nbsp;Poppleford&nbsp;Weather</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="index.htm">Now</a></li>
       <li><a id="click-today" href="today.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="today.htm">Today</a></li>
    <li><a id="click-yesterday" href="yesterday.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="yesterday.htm">Yesterday</a></li>
    <li><a id="click-thismonth" href="thismonth.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="thismonth.htm">This&nbsp;Month</a></li>
    <li><a id="click-thisyear" href="thisyear.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="thisyear.htm">This&nbsp;Year</a></li>
    <li><a id="click-records" href="records.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="records.htm">Records</a></li>
    <li><a id="click-trends" href="trends.htm" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="trends.htm">Trends</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Comment: No problem. Sorry I was a bit lazy with my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your .navbar CSS to:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code but couldn't find .navbar .navbar-nav { } in any of the code.

Comment: They are on bootstrap.css, just find .navbar via ctrl+f or cmd+f

Comment: You better [unminify](http://unminify.com/) the css code first if you need to edit them

Comment: Sorry, this didn't center the navbar as you can see from the link in the post.

Comment: You could try by inject the css directly to your html `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-nav" style="float:none">`